# Synchronization of 2 Mutex in 2 methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization

I have 2 methods TIC and TAC which just output "TIC" or "TAC". And my goal is after creating multiple threads of TIC and TAC.
Final result should be:
TIC TAC TIC TAC TIC TAC

Here i create threads.

```
Class1 a = new ();

Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => a.TIC());
Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => a.TIC());
Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => a.TIC());

Thread thread4 = new Thread(() => a.TAC());
Thread thread5 = new Thread(() => a.TAC());
Thread thread6 = new Thread(() => a.TAC());

thread3.Start();
thread5.Start();
thread2.Start();
thread6.Start();
thread4.Start();
thread1.Start();

thread1.Join();
thread2.Join();
thread3.Join();
thread4.Join();
thread5.Join();
thread6.Join();
```

And here TIC and TAC methods

```
public class Class1
{
    public Mutex mutexTIC = new Mutex(true);
    public Mutex mutexTAC = new Mutex(false);

    public void TIC()
    {
        mutexTIC.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("TIC");

        mutexTAC.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    public void TAC()
    {
        mutexTAC.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("TAC");
        mutexTIC.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

also i tried to add lock, add Mutexs as parameters, tried to use event.
But every time i get this System.ApplicationException: 'Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.'. And i have 0 idea how fix it.
I'm sorry for any unclearence. Hope i explained enough.

Comment: Why are you starting the threads in this weird order, and not from 1 to 6 like when you `Join` them?

Comment: Are you interested to know why are you getting these `ApplicationException` exceptions, or you want to know how to produce a specific TIC/TAC pattern? In the second case, could you edit the question and include the desirable output of your program, after all 6 threads have completed?

Comment: @reply i'm starting threads in weird order to be sure that my code will work in any circumstance. Actually both i'm was curious why i getting this exception and i want to know how to produce it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this exception because you are using `Mutex` incorrectly: you are taking `mutexTIC` on the main thread, where `Class1` is created, but then attempt to release it on a different thread. This restriction exists because `Mutex` wraps an OS kernel mutex object which (at least on Windows) enforces these threading rules. `ManualResetEvent` and relatives also wrap kernel synchronization objects and have similar restrictions. However, in a managed program, one almost never needs to use these legacy objects (the exception is when you need them to synchronize with other processes or with unmanaged code). Instead of `Mutex`, use a managed synchronization object with less restrictive rules, such as `SemaphoreSlim`:

```cs
// in Class1:
public SemaphoreSlim mutexTIC = new (1, 1);
public SemaphoreSlim mutexTAC = new (0, 1);

public void TIC()
{
    mutexTIC.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("TIC");

    mutexTAC.Release();
}

public void TAC()
{
    mutexTAC.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("TAC");
    mutexTIC.Release();
}
```

Note that this code is fine as a toy example, but if `TIC()` and `TAC()` did something non-trivial that could throw an exception, you would need to be very careful with exception and error handling so as not to leak semaphore counts and create a deadlock.